# Failed to load vuetify stylesheets in vitest

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vitest, vuetifyjs3

I started to create an application with Nuxt 3 and Vuetify 3, the web application is working fine.

Now I started to write the unit tests for pages using vitest, when I got an error like `Can't find stylesheet to import`. (unit test for components and state management works fine)

We are using Nuxt 3, Vuetify 3, typescript, pinia and vitest for application development.

vitest.config.ts

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import Vuetify from '@vuetify/vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [Vue(), Vuetify({styles: 'sass'})],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@@': __dirname,
        },
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
        deps: {
            inline: [/@nuxt\/test-utils-edge/],
        },
    },
});
```

nuxt.config.ts

```
import {defineNuxtConfig} from 'nuxt';

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    typescript: {
        typeCheck: 'build',
        strict: true,
    },
    css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', 'mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
    },
    vite: {
        define: {
            'process.env.DEBUG': false,
        },
    },
    buildModules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
});
```

test/pages/export/index.test.ts (test)

```
import {describe, test, expect} from 'vitest';
import {setup, $fetch} from '@nuxt/test-utils-edge';

describe('exportPage', async () => {
    await setup({
        server: true,
    });
    test('Check export title', async () => {
        const html = await $fetch('/export');
        expect(html).toContain('Export data');
    });
});
```

Dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/test-utils-edge": "3.0.0-rc.4-27588443.cf25525",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "0.32.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^10.0.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "0.1.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.27.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.27.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "2.0.0",
    "@vuetify/vite-plugin": "^1.0.0-alpha.11",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.1.0",
    "jsdom": "^20.0.0",
    "mdi": "2.2.43",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.4",
    "pinia": "2.0.14",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "sass": "1.52.3",
    "typescript": "4.7.3",
    "vitest": "0.15.1",
    "vuetify": "3.0.0-beta.4"
  }
```

Test failure screen

[image]

How can I import vuetify stylesheets for vitest?

If anyone has any solution, please share. I will be grateful to you.

Answer (score -1):

I ran across this issue too. Changing nuxt.config.ts from:

```
css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', 'mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css']
```

to:

```
css: ['vuetify/styles', 'mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css']
```

did the trick for me